# Schema returned by JOIN SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'am pretty new to T-SQL. Is actually possible to change value, returned by JOIN statement? For example I have table with column in `float`. It returns with a JOIN. But I want to convert this column into `varchar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.  Just convert it in your `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), table2.field) AS field
FROM table1
JOIN table2 on ...
```

Or use [`STR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx) if you want to specify the length and precision:

```
SELECT
STR(table2.field, 10, 2) AS field
FROM table1
JOIN table2 on ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`CAST()` is another option.

```
SELECT
    CAST(B.returned_value as varchar(40)) [returned_value]
FROM
    TableA A
    INNER JOIN TableB B ON A.id = B.fk_id
```